# What is the closest experimental platform to $H=\sum_{ij} J^X_{ij}X_iX_j+J^Y_{ij}Y_iY_j+J^Z_{ij}Z_iZ_j$?

Tags: hamiltonian-simulation, experimental-realization, ising-model

Consider the Hamiltonian
$$H=\sum_{ij} J^X_{ij}X_iX_j+J^Y_{ij}Y_iY_j+J^Z_{ij}Z_iZ_j$$
where $X,Y,Z$ are Pauli spin operators and $J_{ij}^\alpha$ are arbitrary couplings that can be positive and negative.

**What would be the most adapted experimental platform to simulate such a Hamiltonian ?**

I see that this could be implemented on a Rydberg computer by troterizing in the following way: apply the ZZ interaction, then rotate each qubit to the Y basis, then apply YY (using ZZ) then rotate again, then apply XX (using ZZ) then rotate back to the Z basis. Negative couplings can also be implemented by inserting local rotations.
However, this does not seem efficient, is there a platform that would be physically closer to this $H$ ?